# It acts as a booking system allowing user to create an account, create bookings and cancel bookings

Tags: python, beginner

As the title says, it manages to create accounts, create bookings and cancel them. I am relatively new to coding, so i was wondering how did i do? What are some improvements that i could do? Any reviews are appreciated.

```
AccountsD = {"Josh": "123456", "Michael": "212121"}
days = ["monday", "tuesday", "wednesday", "thursday", "friday", "saturday", "sunday"]
bookings = [('monday', 12)]
accountBook = []

def main():
    username = input("Enter your username: ")
    userpass = input("Enter your password: ")
    account(username, userpass)

def account(username, userpass):
    while True:
        try:
            if username not in AccountsD:
                conf = input("You dont have an account yet, do you want to create one?(y/n) ").lower()
                if conf == 'n':
                    print("Sorry could not create a booking as there is no account")
                    return False
                elif conf == 'y':
                    creat = input("Do you want to use the same details?(y/n) ").lower()
                    if creat == 'y':
                        AccountsD[username] = userpass
                        print("Account has been created")
                        securityCheck()
                        break
                    elif creat == 'n':
                        username2 = input("What username do you want to use? ")
                        userpass2 = input("What password do you want to use? ")
                        if username2 not in AccountsD:
                            AccountsD[username2] = userpass2
                            securityCheck()
                            return False
                        else:
                            print("username already in use")
                    else:
                        print("Sorry can only take y/n")
        except:
            pass

def securityCheck():
     global menucheck1
     while True:
        try:
            menucheck1 = input("\nPlease Log in!\nPlease enter your username: ")
            menucheck2 = input("Please enter your password: ")
            if menucheck1 in AccountsD:
                if AccountsD[menucheck1] == menucheck2:
                    print("\nInformation is Correct!")
                    mainMenu()
                    return False
                else:
                    print("Invalid Password")
            else:
                print("Username is invalid")
        except:
            pass



def mainMenu():
    while True:
        try:
            print("\nAvailable Actions: \nCreate a booking \nCancel a booking")
            print(f"\nAccount: \nUsername: {menucheck1}")
            print("Bookings: ")
            for i in accountBook:
                print(f"{i[0].capitalize()} at {i[1]}:00")
            choice = input("\nWelcome, what action do you want to do?(book, cancel, exit) ").lower()
            if choice == "exit":
                print(f"\nExiting System \n\n{menucheck1}'s Bookings:")
                for i in accountBook:
                    print(f"{i[0].capitalize()} at {i[1]}:00")
                return False
            elif choice == "book":
                book()
                return False
            elif choice == "cancel":
                cancel()
                return False
            else:
                print("Sorry unexpected action.")
        except:
            pass

def book():
    while True:
        try:
            date = input("\nWhat day would you like to book? ").lower()
            if date not in days:
                print("Choose a valid day")
                continue
            time = int(input("What time do you want to book?(Hourly 8-22) "))
            if 22 < time or time < 8:
                print("Invalid time, choose a time from 8 to 22")
            if (date, time) not in bookings:
                bookings.append((date, time))
                accountBook.append((date, time))
                print(f"Booking has been created for {date.capitalize()} at {time}:00 o'clock")
                another = input("Do you want to create anoter booking? (y/n) ")
                if another == "y":
                    continue
                elif another == "n":
                    mainMenu()
                    return False
                else:
                    print("Please enter either y or n.")
                    continue
            else:
                print("Sorry that time is taken")
        except ValueError:
            print("Please enter a valid time")
            pass

def cancel():
    while True:
        try:
            print(f"{menucheck1}'s Bookings:")
            for i in accountBook:
                print(f"{i[0].capitalize()} at {i[1]}:00")
            cancelDate = input("\nWhat day would you like to cancel? ").lower()
            cancelTime = int(input(f"What time would you like to cancel for {cancelDate.capitalize()}? "))
            if (cancelDate, cancelTime) not in accountBook:
                print("You do not have a booking at this date/time.")
                continue
            accountBook.remove((cancelDate, cancelTime))
            bookings.remove((cancelDate, cancelTime))
            print(f"Booking removed for {cancelDate.capitalize()} at {cancelTime}:00")
            rem = input("Do you want to cancel anymore bookings? (y/n) ")
            if rem == "y":
                continue
            elif rem == "n":
                mainMenu()
                return False
            else:
                print("Enter either y or n.")
                continue
        except:
            print("Please enter correct values")
            pass


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 1):

Here are some thoughts. First, I will have some suggestions from running your code on how you might be able to improve on what the user experiences and then I will make some comments on the code itself.

**Hide Passwords**

When the user is prompted for a password, the password is inputted using the `input` function and therefore the characters typed are echoed on the screen for the world to see. Users have come to expect that the password will *not* be echoed, which provides a measure of security. Therefore, use `getpass.getpass()` for this operation.

**Improved Login/Create Account Flow**

On running your program I am immediately asked to enter my user id and password. Since I did not have an existing account I just entered return (thus, specifying an empty string) for both values, which your program accepted. Surely, an empty string should not be valid user id nor password. After I was told I did not have an account, I was then asked if I wanted to use what I had entered as "the same (login) details." Even if I had entered something other than empty strings, I don't think this is the best practice.

On running your program the user should be entered with a menu with three choices: **Login**, **Create New Account** and **Exit**. If the user chooses Login and then enters something invalid, then the same three-item menu is re-displayed. If the user chooses to create a new account, in keeping with current standards, the user should be asked for the password twice, the second being a confirmation. You might also wish to have a rule that defines what constitutes a valid, secure password so that the user cannot select just any password.

After I entered my user id and password and then logged in, you displayed:

```None
Information is Correct!

Available Actions:
Create a booking
Cancel a booking

Account:
Username: Booboo
Bookings:

Welcome, what action do you want to do?(book, cancel, exit)
```

It seems to me that a more logical ordering would be:

```None
You are logged in as Booboo!

Bookings:

Available Actions:
Create a booking
Cancel a booking

Welcome, what action do you want to do?(book, cancel, exit)
```

I then entered **cancel** when I had no bookings and was displayed:

```None
Booboo's Bookings:

What day would you like to cancel?
```

This makes little sense to me since I have no booking so what can I be canceling? **cancel** should not be an option when the user has nothing to cancel.

**I then got into an endless loop with your program that I could not get out of because I could not enter any valid values.** The user always needs some way to escape from a function.

**Improved Menu System**

I don't want to have to type in words like **cancel**. It would be better to display instead something like:

```None
Welcome! What action would you like to do?
1: Book
2: Cancel
3. Exit
```

Or:

Welcome! What action would you like to do? **B**ook, **C**ancel, e**X**it

The user then has to enter only a single number or (case-insensitive) letter depending on what style of choices you adopt.

**Have Reusable Menu Logic**

You should create one or more reusable, general-purpose functions for prompting the user and getting their response. For example, if you adopt my suggestion of numbering possible valid responses where it makes sense and then the user only has to enter a number, you could define a function that would do this:

```py
def get_menu_choice(choices: tuple):
    """Create and put out a numeric menu and return the user's selection.
    Arguments:
    choices -- A tuple of strings describing the valid input options.
              For example:
              ('Login', 'Create New Account', Exit)
              In this case what will be displayed to the user is:
              1. Login
              2. Create New Account
              3. Exit
              Enter your numerical selection:

              The user can then enter 1, 2 or 3 and what will be returned
              is the corresponding command such as 'Create New Account' if 2
              is entered.
    """
    while True:
        for menu_item_number, choice in enumerate(choices, start=1):
            print(f'{menu_item_number}. {choice}')
        selection = input('Enter your numerical selction: ')
        try:
            # Can generate a ValueError
            selection = int(selection) - 1
            # Can generate an IndexError
            return choices[selection]
        # These are expected exceptions:
        except ValueError:
            pass
        except IndexError:
            pass
        print('Invalid selection.', end='\n\n')
```

Here we decided that this function will return the actual command string. We could have returned instead an integer that specified which choice was selected.

Function `mainMenu` now then becomes:

```py
def mainMenu():
    CREATE = 'Create a booking'
    CANCEL = 'Cancel a booking'
    EXIT = 'Exit'

    print("Bookings: ")
    for i in accountBook:
        print(f"{i[0].capitalize()} at {i[1]}:00")

    print("\nWelcome, what action do you want to do?")

    choice = get_menu_choice(
        (
            CREATE,
            CANCEL,
            EXIT
        )
    )

    if choice == EXIT:
        print(f"\nExiting System \n\n{menucheck1}'s Bookings:")
        for i in accountBook:
            print(f"{i[0].capitalize()} at {i[1]}:00")
    elif choice == CREATE:
        book()
    elif choice == "CANCEL":
        cancel()
```

**Note that `mainMenu` has no idea nor cares how the choices are displayed and user input is peformed.** You can change your approach and only `mainMenu` needs to be modified.

`get_menu_choice` may not be applicable when you are trying to input, for example, the hour of the day. But you could create a function that takes a prompt string and a list of valid responses and reuse that function where appropriate. But always provide the user the ability to escape back to the main menu where they can then exit if they wish to.

**Comments and Docstrings**

Your functions should have comments and/or a Docstring so the reader (me!) can understand what is being done.

**Save User Credentials and Bookings to a File**

You should have your users and their bookings define externally and read them in at program run time. Whenever a change/addition/deletion is made to a booking or user, the external store should be updated. This external store could be, for example, a SQLite database or even a text file that holds a serialized form of your objects (for example, see the `json` module).